# Creating a line that goes until the margin

Tags: width

I understand that I can use the command `\underline{\textwdith}}` to get a line that stretches from one side of the page to the other, but what if I want to have some text first and then have the line continue from where the words stop to the edge of the page?

Comment: Try: `Some text, some text \hrulefill`.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Thank you so much!

Comment: and rather than `\underline{\textwdith}}` please use `\hrule`